# Copy same data on each worksheet (there are about 80) on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to be able to copy and paste the cells from sheet 1 onto all the sheets in my workbook.

Is there a quick way to do this, so in one go, rather than go to each individual sheet and click paste?

The data in each sheet will be pasted in the same cells.

Answer (score 3):

This is how to do it:

- Select the data in Sheet 1
- Copy using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- Click the tab for Sheet 2 and then click inside this tab where
  the paste of the selected cells will start
- Holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, click the tab for the last sheet
- Paste using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

After choosing multiple sheets, `[Group]` appears in the title bar at the
top of the worksheet. To cancel the group, click any unselected worksheet, or
right-click the tab of any selected sheet and click *Ungroup Sheets*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't realise this was possible. However, it appears that the data is not pasted to the same location in the target sheets as it was copied from in the source sheet. Instead, it is copied to the currently selected location in each sheet (A1 by default).

Comment: great answer, as for comment @Blackwood before you select ALL the sheets, click into the cell where you want the data pasted, then select all sheets and paste, so if you copy C2:H2, select cell C2 on the sheet where you will be pasting, then select all sheets etc. hope that makes sense

Comment: @PeterH Yes. As I said, the data is copied to the currently selected location in each sheet. Selecting the desired location in each of 80 worksheets is about as time consuming as pasting separately to each sheet.

Comment: @Blackwood you only need to select the location on first of the sheets you paste to, and it will use that location on ALL of the sheets, try it for yourself it works for me.

Comment: My apologies @PeterH, you are correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Blackwood no worries, glad you got it working, this was new to me also, but VERY useful for filling out a skills matrix list across 92 tabs every time an employee leaves or joins

Comment: @PeterH: Thanks for making it clear. I have added this missing piece to my answer.